# How to wait for Web Query to complete in Excel VBA Macro

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, microsoft-excel-365

I have an Excel file that uses an API to lookup some data from a website.  It is built using the standard "Get Data from Web" built in PowerQuery feature of Excel.  I run a macro to update the query, which is set to run in the background so that I can keep working while it executes.  I have another macro that needs to also run, but not until the first one is complete.  To update the single query, I can easily call this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - USPS_ZipLookup").Refresh
```

However, I cannot figure out how to determine that it is complete.  I am aware of techniques like adding `Application.Wait` however this locks up the program for a period and there is no way to know how many seconds the query may take to run (sometimes it is fast, other times slow).  I can also fake a delay by looping `Do ... Loop` a large number of times (this is non-blocking) however again I cannot be sure the query is actually finished.  I know there are ways to check this if I were querying directly from a database connection, but cannot find the way to do it for a basic web query.  Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried adding a Wait option in the Power Query itself?

Comment: @FlexYourData "Wait" requires a specific duration.  This query could take an unknown amount of time, so I need to measure the state of the query not just an arbitrary time.

Comment: Try adding a custom column to your web query. Name it “Last Refresh” and use the column formula `= DateTime.LocalNow()`. Then you can get the last refresh date/time by checking any value in the column before refreshing the query, and determine when it’s complete by checking any value again to confirm that it’s changed.